# Python - How to process my JSON FormData on the backend in Python?

Tags: python, json, post, request, fetch

I'm a complete beginner and i'm little bit lost.

Here's my application:

on the front-end i have a react form and i use fetch to send my form data to my backend:

```
fetch('/process.py', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({data})
        })
```

on the backend i have a simple file python file, i don't how to process the data that i just received

Comment: What is your backend code? What is the python file?

Comment: We only know that it's `process.py`. But Python source code files aren't automagically exposed to HTTP clients.

Comment: @ShikharChauhan  just a little script that i used to transform some hardcoded JSON to a Dataframe object. But now what i'm trying to do is to replace that hardcoded JSON by my FormData JSON

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo how can i expose it ?

Answer (score 0):

If we could see a some of your python script, that would help clarify, but I'm assuming that you're not sure what to do with your return.

You can parse a json return with the json or yaml module.

this website: http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/scenarios/json/ seems to give a nice description of what to do.

with your return as some var,

```
import json
var = [json_data]
data = json.loads(var)
```

from here, you can parse your return as a dictionary

Comment: Thank you but i have no issue with my hardcoded JSON, the main problem is to connect my front-end and my back-end

Comment: Could you please throw up that python file? That would help us answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i decided to try Flask and it works just fine.

process.py:

```
from flask import Flask, request, json, abort
from flask_cors import cross_origin

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/foo', methods=['POST'])
@cross_origin(origin='localhost', headers=['Content- Type',   'Authorization'])
def foo():
if not request.json:
    abort(400)
print(request.json)
return json.dumps(request.json)


if __name__ == '__main__':
 app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5050, debug=True)
```

my fetch:

```
fetch('http://127.0.0.1:5555/foo', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({data})
    })
```

Answer (score -2):

It's been a while since I've done http servers with python, so I'm sure there's a more "correct"/modern answer, but I quite liked using tornado: http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/http.html

Either way you will need to find some library to create an http server to send requests to.